# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" netbeans error

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using this code :

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    double cTotal1=Double.parseDouble(costdrink.getText());
    double cTotal2=Double.parseDouble(jtxtmaterial.getText());
    double ctotal3=Double.parseDouble(cost_Delivery.getText());
    double altotal = (cTotal1 + cTotal2 + ctotal3);
    String itotal = String.format("Rs %.2f", altotal);
    jcomtotal.setText(itotal);
}
```

it is not working..
it gives these errors as shown belown..

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Rs 15.00"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1224)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at restaurant.Restaurant1.jButton4ActionPerformed(Restaurant1.java:1067)
    at restaurant.Restaurant1.access$700(Restaurant1.java:39)
    at restaurant.Restaurant1$8.actionPerformed(Restaurant1.java:268)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6031)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3261)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5796)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2056)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4403)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2114)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4233)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4249)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3913)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3843)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2100)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2438)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4233)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: `Rs` cannot be parsed as a number...

Comment: so then what i have do...

Comment: Parse it yourself so to extract the number. Also your code is not complete, we have to guess what `jcomtotal` is.

Comment: jcomtotal is textfield that will display final data.

Comment: thanx. problem solved. thank you again.